# Documentary series in one episode they attacked a casino

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I am trying to get the name of a tv series which had R. Paul Wilson from 'The Real Hustle' in it.

The episode I saw was when he performed a penetration test on a casino with some colleagues he picked up using a special kind of transmitter they made.  It went wrong and they got caught and arrested, although they were freed again of course as the owner had hired them.  The camera crew was explained to staff as being part of a documentary being filmed in the casino.

Actually I saw part of another episode, it involved a pool hustler in a bar who was spoiling things by always thrashing everyone (or something) and Paul brought some women in who played the guy for a load of money (she was some kind of pool champion) and she won the match.

Does anyone know what the series was called, I really enjoyed this and would like to see some more of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be Derren Brown's ["Derren Brown: The Events"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1509646/) series. This had an episode titled ["How to Take Down a Casino"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1526795/).

**Updated:**

The other series it could be is ["The Takedown"](http://www.tv.com/shows/the-takedown/episodes/) season 1:

> [Episode 2: Shootout at Mr. Lucky's](http://www.tv.com/shows/the-takedown/shootout-at-mr-luckys-433151/)
>
> Paul Wilson and the gang head to a pool hall where pool sharks have
> been known to invade and have created a serious problem for the owner
> of the hall. They recruit the help of one of the top pool players in
> the world. It's her task to "hussle the hussler". However, he's a lot
> tougher than she expected, and he really gets into her head by trash
> talking. It is a nail biting competition for a while, but she manages
> to defeat him. As Paul Wilson says, "you'll probably never see him
> here again."

There are various episodes such as these where they try to beat the casino using gadgets:

> [Episode 6: Gone in Sixty Minutes](http://www.tv.com/shows/the-takedown/gone-in-sixty-minutes-466912/)
>
> Paul and his team try to cheat at a roulette wheel using computers.
>
> [Episode 10: Beating the Bandits](http://www.tv.com/shows/the-takedown/shootout-at-mr-luckys-433151/)
>
> Paul takes his team to the Fitzgerald's Casino in Las Vegas. They use light wands to try and rip off multiple slot machines.

Comment: Thanks, I can see why you thought it was that but it was not.  This was presented and narrated by Paul the entire way though and did not feature Derren.

Comment: @Stefan - see my update.